# Why the value of the combobox display too long?

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

I've got a dataGridView, then set combobox for cell by code as below:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> kvp in mapDataDisplay)
{
    // Create combobox cell
    var dgvCbbCell = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();

    // Set DisplayStyle
    dgvCbbCell.DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.ComboBox;

    for (int ii = 0; ii < listItemCbb.Count; ii++)
    {
        dgvCbbCell.Items.Add(listItemCbb[ii]);
    }

    dgvCbbCell.Value = kvp.Value;

    // Set combobox for cell
    dataGridView[IDX_COL_CBB, kvp.Key] = dgvCbbCell;
}
```

But when run, it display the value of the combobox is too long.

What is the happens? Please tell me? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: You could try to set the `.DropDownWidth` to the width of the cell

Comment: Thank you for reply! I tried but did not work.

Comment: If you don't have an item that contains a value long enough for the wrapper to get such width (as your image shows) then you have somewhere a fixed width for your list container. It's a css question. You should see the classes applied to your list and their attributes to figure out which one gives this width to your wrapper.

Comment: Thank you for relpy! I'm still investigating where to affect the width of the combobox...

Comment: In my entire source code there is no place to fix the width of the combobox. I create the combobox with the code above.

Comment: Just look at the code snippet in the [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcell(v=vs.110).aspx), shows how to use DataGridViewComboBoxColumn and set its DropdownWidth property.